# Exponentiation of cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How to prove that $a^{x}\leq b^{y}$ for any cardinal number a,b, $x,y$ with a$\leq$b , $x\leq y$?

First, I want to show that $p^r\leq\ q^r$ and $r^p\leq\ r^q$ for any cardinal number $p,q,r$ with $p\leq q$.

If $P,Q,R$ are sets such that $cardP=p, cardQ=q, cardR=r,$ it is easy to show that $p^r\leq\ q^r$ because $P$ is equipotent with some subset of $Q$

But I don't know how to show that $r^p\leq\ r^q$

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $C^D$ is the set of functions from $D$ to $C$.

Without loss of generality, assume $P\subseteq Q$.

If $q=0$ then the statement is trivial (because then $p=0$ as well), therefore assume $q>0$, that is, $Q$ is not empty. Therefore you can choose a single element $a\in Q$ (there are no further requirements on $a$).

Now you can define a map $\phi:R^P\to R^Q$ as follows:
$$\phi(f)(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & x\in P\\
a & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
It is not hard to check that $\phi$ is indeed an injection, and therefore $|R^P|\le |R^Q|$, that is, $r^p\le r^q$.

Comment: Why assume that $P\subseteq Q$.? If $P$ is not a subset of $Q$, how to show that?

Comment: @Right_No: $|P|\le|Q|$ means there is an injection from $P$ to $Q$. If you choose a general $P$, you have to always talk about the unique element of $P$ that maps mto a given element in the image of $P$ in $Q$. But the only thing that matters is the cardinality of $P$ and the existence of that injection, therefore there is no loss if we choose $P$ to be a subset and the injection to be the inclusion map (that maps every element to itself). We lose nothing, but save a lot of writing with no substantial value.